# MySQL Assuming unsigned result in subtractions, what's the motive?

Tags: mysql

I just found out that if I try to subtract an unsigned integer from another unsigned, MySQL automatically assumes the result will be unsigned, which in turn generates the error `BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range` whenever the actual result of the operation is negative.

I tried googling the reason for this design decision, but didn't find any explanation.

What are the motives for such a decision? does it make sense to assume an unsigned result when subtracting two unsigned integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch-22.
I'll use `TINYINT` to make the numbers easier.  `SIGNED` range is -128..127; `UNSIGNED` is 0..255

Your question, as I see it, is "Why not make the result `SIGNED`?"

Your case is (10) - (12) = (-2), which cannot be represented as `UNSIGNED`.

A different case is (200) - (1) = (199), which cannot be represented as `SIGNED`.

Either decision leads to *some* arguments producing an value that is "out of range".

(I don't know the history of the decision.  Also, I don't know if there is an SQL standard that is involved.)

Comment: I see, I hadn't thought about cases where unsigned values where high enough for `SIGNED` to not be able to represent them. Thanks, now it makes sense!

Comment: Logically, if you want something unsigned, presumably you've done it for a reason - quantity_on_hand can never be negative, so if you try and fulfill an order in a warehouse that has more items in it than are available, it makes sense to throw an error!